# Unrecognized ports in wildfly

Tags: wildfly8

My standalone wildfly instance is listening to the following ports:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 6116
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8777                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6116/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10990               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6116/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41908               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6116/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8090              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6116/java
```

I only recognizes 8777 and 8090. How can I find out what the other two ports are for? I used a company template to configure my standalone.xml file. So it could be that there is some subsystem or interface that I need to disable. I know the following:

- it is standalone deployment (not managed domain)
- I grep'ed all wildfly standalone config files (including standalone.xml) for those port numbers but yield nothing.
- I tried this `bin/jboss-cli.sh --controller=localhost:8090 -c command=":read-resource(include-runtime=true, recursive=true, recursive-depth=10)" | grep 10990` again yeild nothing.
- I have been looking into the documentation but without a clue, it has been like searching a needle in heystack.

Is there a cli command to find out which component/interface is opening what ports? What's the best way to start finding out what these ports are for?

Comment: Reading Wildfly documentation?

Comment: Well, I am accustomed to negative votes once in a while, so I am not surprised. I never ask questions without doing my homework first (i.e reading the documentation, searching for existing questions). For this case, I have already been like an hour into the documentation and I am not making any progress in finding a solution for this. Someone who is familiar with wildfly can very easily point out where to look. It's disappointing this community is so uptight in judging a question by it's cover.

Comment: Well, mentioning that there is nothing in the documentation about the ports helps in these cases. Most often people here just ask things without doing their homework. I'm sorry for assuming the same in your case.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Ok, that make sense. Thanks for letting me know. Now I know what's wrong, I updated the ticket. (if you have downvoted before, would you mind removing your downvote if you think my question is now ok)

Comment: Someone's probably changed the default JBoss ports. Check your configuration carefully.